# Tmux copy mode: stay in copy mode after selection

Tags: vim, tmux, productivity

When using tmux, I often find a need to copy multiple items from one pane or window into another. When those items are located close to each other in a long scrollback buffer, my current workflow typically goes like this:

1. Enter the copy mode in the source pane
2. Select the first item and copy it.
3. Go to the target pane
4. Paste the first item where I want
5. Go back to the source pane
6. Enter the copy mode
7. Select the second item and copy it
8. Go to the target pane
9. Paste the second item.

This is very inefficient. I was looking for a shortcut to get the two items into the buffer within a single invocation of the copy mode. I could then use the buffer stack, pick the items and paste them sequentially in the target pane. This would shave off a few keystrokes, but the bulk of my work lies in locating the appropriate selections in the scrollback.

But right now, as soon as I press a key to select something in the copy mode, tmux quits the copy mode. I really like how I can stay in vim's visual mode after making a selection, using `gV`. Is there something similar that I could do in tmux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be that there is no such feature right now. But there is a ticket in their SF page about this: http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tickets/174/. I hope the issue will be fixed soon.

Comment: That link is dead now. Was it transferred to github?